# Electron 6.0.9 webview load any urls are blank

Tags: javascript, electron

I use electron official sample "https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/webview/browser"

with following cmd:

```
/home/roroco/.node/node_modules/bin/electron /home/roroco/Downloads/js/electron-sample-apps/webview/browser/main.js
```

the electron window console has not any error

[image]

I try to open webview devtools but it doesn't open

```
  const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
  webview.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    webview.openDevTools()
  })
```

I guess it's linux env problem, maybe windows and mac has this bug, here is my env:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads/js/electron-sample-apps $ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa
Release:    19.1
Codename:   tessa
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution, in electron, webview feature default is disable, I should manually enable it

see https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/breaking-changes.md#new-browserwindow-webpreferences-

with following code:

new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, height: 600,
    webPreferences: {webviewTag: true}
  })